# How do I password protect all but one URL in Django without authentication?

Tags: django

Is there a tool that allows me to password protect all but one URL in Django without requiring authentication?

Answer (score 2):

you can use **@loging_required** decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

on all your views except that one view/url.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) for this:

```
class LoggedInUserCheckMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        full_path = request.get_full_path()
        if not full_path == '/no-need-auth-url' and not request.user.is_authenticated:
           raise Http404

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

And add it to `MIDDLEWARE` in settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # rest of middlewares
    'path.to.LoggedInUserCheckMiddleware'
]
```